# Как запустить Telegram из скрипта в crontab?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, crontab

В crontab имеется задача, ежеминутно запускающая bash скрипт. В скрипте есть строка

```
/home/111/.Telegram/Telegram -workdir /home/111/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/ -autostart
```

Взял ее из пункта в автозагрузки Телеграмма. Ввожу строку в терминале, запускается Телеграмм. Но вот из этого скрипта никак. Права 755, владелец 111. Debian 11, xfce. Ставил в скрипт notify-send "111" и он тоже не запускается. Проблема как я понимаю не в строке, а более глобальна. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Запускаясь с крона скрипт не видит дисплея и поэтому не может открыть окно.

Исправить можно добавив в скрипт в начале.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
```

Но лучше [переходи на таймеры](https://gist.github.com/oprypin/0f0c3479ab53e00988b52919e5d7c144) в `~/.config/systemd/user/`